# How to write Unit Tests for injected Springboot service

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, amazon-s3, mockito

This is the my UploadClass. And it uploads a file to the S3 bucket using S3Client.

```
 public class UploadClass{
     @Override
     public void upload(){
          ObjectMetadata metadata = new ObjectMetadata();
          metadata.setContentLength(length);
          PutObjectResult putObjectResult =
                  this.s3Client.putObject(container, object, data, metadata);
        }
    }
```

This is the MyClass and here I have injected the the UploadClass via constructor injection and have used the upload() method of UploadClass.

```
     @Service
        public class MyClassServiceImpl implements MyClassService{
        
          private final UploadClass uploadClass;
         
         @Autowired
          MyClass(final UploadClass uploadClass) {
            this.uploadClass = uploadClass;
        
          }
        
         @Override
          public void process() {
......................Some other work ...................
.....................................................
......................................................
            this.uploadClass.upload();
          }
        }
```

Now I am trying to write Unit tests for the process method in MyClass.And I need to mock the UploadClass using mockito and need to use mock output value for upload() method.This is my MyClassServiceTest class.How can I do this ?

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyClassServiceTest{

 @Test
 void processTest() {

}
}
```

Comment: Some information is missing. How do you instantiate your s3Client? Field injection, constructor injection, other? How do you run your unit test? Using the @SpringBootTest annotation?

Comment: Hi @Fabian, Sorry ..now I have added the missing details. Could you please help me to write the unit test for this :( ?

Comment: You can use mock this object: s3Client via @Mock annotation, details are in: https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-annotations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With given code there is no much to test - only if upload method has been called.

```
@SpringBootTest
public class MyClassServiceTest{
  
@Autowired
 private  MyClassService myService; 
@MockBean
private UploadClass uploadClass
 
 @Test
 void processTest() {
    myService.process();
    //do some assertions
    //.....
    
    verify(uploadClass,times(1)).upload(); //assert that uplaod has been called
}
```

This could be done using plain JunitRunner and Mockito. No need for complete app context.

Comment: Hi @Antoniossss, Thank you for your answer. Actually, I need to test the process() method here as it contains some other work as well, and finally I need to call upload() method inside the process() method, sorry for not mentioning it previously.

Comment: So you have your asnwer already.